# Why does Safari not display some elements even though web inspector shows they are there

Tags: safari

I am struggling with an application using custom elements that is just not working properly in Safari.  Here is a screen shot with what Safari is showing v what it is supposed to show in chrome. It was taken on a Macbook Air, although I originally discovered the issue on an iPad.

[image: Screenshot with Safari and Chrome]

However this screen shot shows that web inspector does think there is an element there whose foreground color is white and opaque (I set those deliberate)  even though nothing is displayed.

[image]

So why is Safari not displaying the elements?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else out there wondering about the same thing.  I think I found the answer!

One of the surrounding elements has some css with `overflow-y: auto`, but without a specific height.  I believe what is happening is that safari has shrunk that element to height 0, but that the inspector is still showing where the element would have been, if its not been hidden by a zero length scroll bar, scrolled so that item is below the cutoff area of the scrollable element.

I haven't yet figured out why it works in chrome, my guess is slightly different handling of overflow.